# Draw IplImage on picturebox in vc++ is slower

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I am drawing iplimage on picturebox by converting it into bitmap.

Bitmap ^imgBitmap = gcnew  Bitmap(ipl->width,ipl->height,ipl->widthStep,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)ipl->imageData);

pictureBox1->Image = imgBitmap;

But I can not run this method to show 50 frames per second. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: How did you came up with the conclusion that this is the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: Showing iplimage in cvShowWindow is faster than drawing the frame on picturebox. When I draw frames on picturebox on 10ms timer the output is not smooth. Its very slow

Comment: My first thought was that the constructor of `Bitmap` was copying the pixels from `IplImage`, that certainly would slow things, but [according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx) it doesn't perform a copy operation. The bottleneck is probably some other part of your code.